# Delphi 10 Seattle project high memory usage

Tags: memory, project, delphi-10-seattle

I had Delphi 10 Seattle installed and some VCL and in-house built components, the project I am working on seems a bit laggy (happens to me only, not to my colleagues), here are the memory usage:
1)
- Opened Seattle ~40MB
- Opened the project ~535MB
- Compiled the project ~1.2GB

2)
- Closed the project ~800MB
- Closed Seattle - 0MB
- Opened Seattle ~40MB
- Opened the project ~535MB
- Built the project ~1.9GB

I am wondering if my project settings has something to do with it?
Thanks

Comment: How big is your code? What kind of uses do you have? Do you use Runtime-Packages?

Comment: From Project -> Options -> Packages
Target: Debug configuration - 32-bit Windows platform
Link with runtime packages is FALSE
Runtime packages:
rtl;vcl;Hydra_Core_D11;xmlrtl;vclimg;vclactnband

Comment: If I do a Build, it shows ~4 million lines of code.